# consuming an array of objects in angularjs and json spring method post

Tags: java, angularjs, json, spring, web-services

I want to consume a web-service that post an array of objects with angularjs, the web-service works fine but when i tried to consume it with angularjs i got an error :Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
My POJO looks like this:

```
package org.test.metier;

import org.test.entities.T_Skill;

public class Skill_Level {

private T_Skill listSkills;
private int level;

// with getters and setters
```

this is my method

```
public T_LinkTalentSkill AddSkills(int lnId,List<Skill_Level> skill_Level) {
T_User u= t_UserRepository.findOne(lnId);
T_Talent t= u.getTalent();

    for(int i=0; i< skill_Level.size(); i++){
        T_LinkTalentSkill linkts =new T_LinkTalentSkill();
        linkts.setTalent(t);
        linkts.setSkill(skill_Level.get(i).getListSkills());
        linkts.setLnLevel(skill_Level.get(i).getLevel());
        linkRepository.save(linkts);
    }
    return null;
}
```

my angularjs code looks like :

```
$rootScope.addSkills=function(){    

            $http.post('/AddSkills/' + $rootScope.lnId, $rootScope.skill_Level).success(function(data) {
                $rootScope.dataa= data;
                });
            };
```

And finally this some HTML

```
<select ng-model="skill_Level[0].listSkills.lnId" class="form-control" id="s2example-1">
                        <option></option>
                            <option ng-repeat="t in listSkill" value="{{t.lnId}}">{{t.strLabel}}</option>
                    </select>
<select ng-model="skill_Level[0].level" class="form-control" id="sboxit-4">
                        <option>Select your country</option>
                        <option value="1">Level 1</option>
                        <option value="2">Level 2</option>
                        <option value="3">Level 3</option>
                        <option value="4">Level 4</option>
                    </select>
```

Any help is apreciated,
Regards

Comment: Post code for `T_Skill` as well.

Comment: I resolved the problem I just switched List by Arraylist and it's works :)

Comment: You can answer your own question as well. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue i just changed List to Arraylist and it's works fine